# Lenovo PW bypass Factory Reset assist

Tags: windows-10, passwords, lenovo-laptop

I need to factory reset upset ex-employee laptop.
Win 10 Lenovo IdeaPad
NOVO button failed to load Boot menu - /stopcode blue screen
Fails to go into safe mode - I get a /stopcode blue screen
F2 brings up IdeaPad Start menu but there is no reset PC option - there is a set User Password option but does not seem to change the login password.
Anyone have any ideas on how I can get this done? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There normally isn’t a way to bypass firmware passwords, as if there was, they would be basically useless

Comment: If you can't find the password, try to enter 3 times a wrong password. If you get a code, contact Lenovo Support with the code and the computer model and ask for help. If there is no code, it's a lost cause.

Comment: So is there even any bios / hdd password set? According to your description, it seems that what you need is an installation medium (disc / USB drive) that allows you to wipe the drive and reinstall Windows (because the current one is broken).

Comment: I think harrymc and I are both correct

Answer (score 0):

> there is a set User Password option but does not seem to change the
> login password.

That is because you need the existing password to change the password (most certainly for Lenovo computers).

Changing the computer password needs to be done in BIOS (function of the computer, not the operating system).

Ask HR to contact the employee and get the password.

Otherwise you need to change the system board and that is likely not economical. In this case just replace the machine.